# Dry or wet etching in fabrication cmos chip?

Tags: transistors, cmos, etching, fabrication, microfabrication

What types of etching are used in conventional chip fabrication technologies such as TSMC 0.18, dry or wet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From:**Introduction to Microfabrication 2nd Edition by Sami Franssila**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470749830)

> Plasma etching is a technology that enables narrow linewidths and high
>   aspect ratios. It has completely replaced wet etching for feature
>   patterning in modern ICs and it is mandatory in polysilicon surface
>   micromechanics. It has also been applied to structures and
>   applications that are not at all possible with wet etching. For
>   instance, plasma etching without resist mask is essential for
>   planarization and spacer formation.

Answer (score 2):

normally dry etching is more common due to its directional (anisotropic) process.
Anisotropic process has the minimum bias (almost 0) and leakage of transistor that fabricate by this characteristic is less than a transistor with wet etching that has a large bias.